# Whenever gem support for ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

Does anyone know if there are any issues with running the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem on ruby 2.0.0? Since I updated ruby, terminal won't recognize the whenever or wheneverize commands.

Comment: It passed all tests for Ruby 2.0 [six days ago](https://travis-ci.org/javan/whenever/jobs/7136243) at the time of this OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the commit history [at github](https://github.com/javan/whenever/commits/master) there's support for ruby 2.0. Try to run the tests and check if they fail or succeed.

To run the tests clone the repo:

> $ git clone https://github.com/javan/whenever.git

run bundle to install dependencies:

> $ cd whenever
>
> $ bundle

and then run the tests:

> $ rake test

I'm using ruby 1.9.3p392 and got this result (only useful to compare the result):

> 215 tests, 464 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Comment: Interesting. All the tests pass and the whenever terminal commands seem to be working just fine. But only in that project.

Comment: Oddly enough, seems it took restarting terminal to make it know about the whenever commands. Thanks for the help with the tests.